# If n is divisible by 2 return true - haskell

Tags: haskell

im trying to do a question in Haskell. I've just begun learning the language and can't get my head around this question.
 I need to return a boolean if n is divisible by 2, it will be true, otherwise false. Heres what i've gotten so far and it doesnt work...

```
is_even :: Int -> Bool 
is_even n 
 | n `mod` 2 == 0 return True
 | otherwise return False
```

Comment: note aside from your error: there is an `odd` and an `even` function that do the job and your function can be simplified `isEven n = n \`mod\` 2 == 0` no need for `= True` and the `otherwise`-branch

Comment: Thanks, a lot simpler !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it myself...

```
is_even :: Int -> Bool 
is_even n 
 | n `mod` 2 == 0 = True 
 |otherwise = False
```

Comment: `if a then True else False == a`